# Use webpart on subsite to read a list on top site

Tags: list, web-part, site, sub-site, runwithelevatedprivileges

I have created SharePoint admin list, where I  have saved a variety of things for webpart. 
Only admins can read the list, I have removed user rights from everyone else.

The following Webpart reads the list using elevated privileges.

```
Guid webID = SPContext.Current.Web.ID;
Guid siteID = SPContext.Current.Site.ID;
    SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
    {
        using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteID))
        {
        // List 'AdminList' does not exist at site with URL 'http://devmach/sites/Test/Subsite'.
            using (SPWeb web = site.AllWebs[webID])
            {
                SPList listsp = web.Lists["AdminList"];
                SPListItemCollection collListItems = listsp.Items;
                foreach (SPListItem itemsp in collListItems)
                {
```

However, when I create new subsite and I add the webpart to the site, it doesn't work, because that subsite does not contain "AdminList".

My question is:

How I can read the list, if the webpart is on a different page?
What changes do I need to make?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use open web, put in the site name for that web, so if i have:

SPSite/SPWeb

mysitecollection.com/mysubsite

it would be:

```
site.OpenWeb("mysubsite")
```

full code:

```
Guid siteID = SPContext.Current.Site.ID;
    SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
    {
        using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteID))
        {
        // List 'AdminList' does not exist at site with URL 'http://devmach/sites/Test/Subsite'.
            using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb("mysubsite"))
            {
                SPList listsp = web.Lists["AdminList"];
                SPListItemCollection collListItems = listsp.Items;
                foreach (SPListItem itemsp in collListItems)
                {
```

the code should only be used to retrive the list, if you want to use the list in many subsites than create it in the sitecollection rather than a subsite!

```
Guid siteID = SPContext.Current.Site.ID;
    SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
    {
        using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteID))
        {
        // List 'AdminList' does not exist at site with URL 'http://devmach/sites/Test/Subsite'.
            using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
            {
                SPList listsp = web.Lists["AdminList"];
                SPListItemCollection collListItems = listsp.Items;
                foreach (SPListItem itemsp in collListItems)
                {
```

first method advanced:

If its a requirement that you need the list within a subsite and need to access it within another subsite than this will do the trick:

get the list from the given subsite you have it on:

```
private SPList getlistFromSite(SPSite site)
{
                SPList listsp = null;
                using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb("mysubsite"))
                {
                    SPList listsp = web.Lists["AdminList"];
                }
                return listsp;
}
```

to use method above but keeping the current site the user is on!:

```
Guid webID = SPContext.Current.Web.ID;
Guid siteID = SPContext.Current.Site.ID;
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{
    using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteID))
    {
        using (SPWeb web = site.AllWebs[webID])
        {
            SPList listsp = getlistFromSite(site);
            SPListItemCollection collListItems = listsp.Items;
            foreach (SPListItem itemsp in collListItems)
            {
                //loop
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: no problem happy to help

Answer (score 2):

You have to know the website that contains AdminList.

Here are two ways to go:

1. Create AdminList in the root web of the site collection and then in your code get the webID of the root web

   ```
   Guid webID = SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb.ID;
   Guid siteID = SPContext.Current.Site.ID;
   SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
   {
       using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteID))
       {
           using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb(webID))
           {
               SPList listsp = web.Lists["AdminList"];
               SPListItemCollection collListItems = listsp.Items;
               foreach (SPListItem itemsp in collListItems)
               {
   ```
2. Add custom property to you webpart so you can set the Url of the list in the webpart's property pane, and use that property in your code to get the list.

   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd584174(v=office.11).aspx
   http://zimmergren.net/technical/how-to-custom-web-part-properties-toolpart